# Limit of sequence without Taylor series

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Consider the sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N^*}, x_1 = 2$ with the recurrence formula:

$$\frac{1}{x_{n+1}^{\frac{1}{n+1}} - 1} - \frac{1}{x_{n}^{\frac{1}{n}} - 1} = 1$$

Evaluate $$\lim _{n \to \infty} x_n$$

I tried calculating some terms and it seems like  $$\lim _{n \to \infty} x_n = e$$

but I really don't know how to start. Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Note sure exactly but here are 2 thoughts. I would try either substituting for the sequence $a_n = x_n^{1/n}$ or computing $x_{n+1}$ directly. It seems like we get
$$
x_{n+1}^{1/(n+1)}
 = 1 + \left(1 + \frac{1}{x_n^{1/n}-1}\right)^{-1}
 = 1 + \left(1 - x_n^{-1/n}\right)
 = 2 - x_n^{-1/n}
$$
so
$$
x_{n+1} = \left(2 - x_n^{-1/n}\right)^{n+1}
$$

Comment: Show by induction that $x_n=(1+1/n)^n$

Comment: @gt6989b you would get that either way.. how this help

Comment: @AbhashJha doing the substitution for example reduces the problem to $$a_{n+1} = 2 - \frac{1}{a_n}$$ which seems more manageable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

To eliminate the inconvenient denominator powers, substitute $a_n = x_n^{1/n}$ to get the recurrence
$$
\frac{1}{a_{n+1}-1} - \frac{1}{a_n-1} = 1
$$
and now let
$$
b_n = \frac{1}{a_n-1}
$$
to get the linear recurrence
$$
b_{n+1} - b_n = 1
$$
which is solvable using ordinary linear methods.